# UIkit HTML horizontal card usage

Tags: html, css, uikit

I am wondering how to add horizontal divs to UIkit's horizontal aligned cards. I have seen media being right-aligned in their documentation [here](https://getuikit.com/docs/card) but have not seen how i can add two divs near one another (one being to the right and one being to the left). The result I get now is: [image]

however I want that green button to be on the right side of the card. The card is created like this:

```
<div id="newBarsCard" style="padding: 40px 0px; padding-top: 0px;" class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-child-width-1-2">
                <div class="uk-clearfix">
                    <div class="uk-float-left uk-card-body" style="position: absolute;">
                        <div class="uk-card-header">
                            <h3 style="" class="uk-card-title uk-margin">${offer.name}</h3>
                            <canvas width="600" height="400"></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <p style="margin-top: ;" class="barCity"><a style="text-decoration: none;">${offer.amount + " TL"}</a></p>
                        <p style="margin-top: ;" class="barCity"><a style="text-decoration: none;">${"Istersen %" + offer.discount + " indirimli!"}</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="" id="${purchaseId}" class="purchaseButton uk-card-body uk-float-right">
                        <p class="barParagraph uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-medium uk-margin-small-top">SATIN AL</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-divider">
    <a href="a">left</a>
    <a href="a">right</a>
</div>
```

or use `<hr class="uk-divider-vertical">`